# Are native JavaScript functions something "superglobals"-like?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor, scope, native

Will the native JavaScript constructors/functions like `Function`, `Object`, `Array` always be available in any scope? Are they inherited by the global object or something like in the same level or even higher?

As an example, MooTools contains the following line in its self executing function:

```
var Function = this.Function;
```

So I asked myself, is there any situation where these native constructors become unavailable? Maybe in server side or strict JS? Or is it just a performance question to cache a local reference? But if so, why not doing it this way:

```
var Function = Function;
```

Comment: The native constructors are global objects (properties of the global object), so yes, they are always available.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, well that's not eternally true. I can easily overwrite them, e.g. `Function=6;` There are tricky ways to refer to them afterwards, but the global references can certainly be lost this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same name, so you can't do that.

```
(function() {
    var Function = Function;

    return Function;
})(); // undefined
```

As to why it's done in the first place? Supposedly to guard against user error or redefinitions, and also to reduce the amount of the scope chain the engine has to look up to find something. Relevant blog post: http://blog.minite.ch/?p=47

Of course, `Function` isn't read-only, so even if someone did redefine `Function` in the global namespace that wouldn't help. Anybody who does this deserves it, though =)

---

EDIT: If they actually did want to protect against user error, a foolproof way would be:

```
var Function = (function() {}).constructor;
```

But it's pointless, as stated above.

Comment: minitech, do you have a link up for that?

Comment: @dollarVar: Ah, sorry for breaking it. http://web.archive.org/web/20120617142826/http://blog.minite.ch/?p=47